# How to find this limit algebraically?

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

for the function

[image]

I am trying to figure out what it means to have f(x) on the numerator, and the algebraic steps necessary to deconstruct this problem

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of derivatives?

Comment: I am vaguely familiar with them, our class has not covered them yet though.

Comment: Can you do this with something like $f(x)=x+2$? How about $f(x)=x^2$? We could better help you if you added such details to your post.

Comment: That is all of the information the problem gives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If
$f(x)
=x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1
$,
what is
$f(x+a)$?

Replacing
$a$ by
$\Delta x$,
what is
$f(x+\Delta x)$?

Finally,
what is
$f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)$?
.

Notice that
in this last difference,
all the terms are
divisible by
$\Delta x$.

So what is the quotient
$\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}$?

What happens to this quotient as
$\Delta x \to 0$?

Comment: Would the value for x be the equation, or its derivative?

Comment: https://www.mathsisfun.com/calculus/derivatives-introduction.html

Comment: The expression you get for the quotient, after letting $\Delta x \to 0$, is the derivative.